# Google Maps e raio de um marcador

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Implementei o código do Google Maps em um site, e exibe marcadores personalizados para todos os endereços no mapa, está ok até aí, tem como personalizar meu mapa para alterar o tipo do marcador se um marcador estiver perto do outro, ou melhor, um marcador ter um raio de 2km, e se outro marcador estiver dentro do mesmo raio, o marcador(ores) ficam de outra cor, ou exibe o raio visualmente no mapa.

Os dados são recuperados do MySQL, dos campos "latitude" e "longitude" da tabela de cadastro, só queria alterar mesmo para um novo marcador os que estiverem se sobrepondo no raio de 2km um do outro.

A imagem está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Todos os marcadores são uma logotipo de cor predominante "Preto", e gostaria de alterar os marcadores sobrepostos por outra logotipo (URL).

O código está assim:

```
<style>
    #map {
       width: 100%;
       height: 600px;
     }
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

        var locations = [
            ['Unidade Vila Osasco', -23.544559, -46.781034, 'Avenida Santo Antônio, 2761, Vila Osasco, São Paulo - SP, 06083-215'],
['Unidade Rebouças', -22.8904057, -43.5603237, 'Avenida Rebouças, 3657, Centro, Sumaré - SP, 13170-023'],
['Unidade Nutrition Bauru', -22.3370765, -49.0891827, 'Avenida Castelo Branco, 7-15, Vila Independência, Bauru - SP, 17052-000'],
['Unidade Pitangueiras', -23.2022764, -46.8836439, 'Rua Pitangueiras, 790, Jardim Pitangueiras, Jundiaí - SP, 13206-716'],
['Unidade Nutrition Vale do Sol', -20.4229151, -49.9592271, 'Avenida pansani, 3092, Vale do sol, Votuporanga - SP, 15500-302'],
['Unidade Cidade Nova Montes Claros-Mg', -16.739527, -43.8653989, 'Avenida Dona Gregória, 101, Cidade Nova, Montes Claros - MG, 39400-464'],
['Unidade Centro Salto', -23.199741, -47.3008818, 'Avenida Dom Pedro II, 1421, Centro, Salto - SP, 13320-241'],
['Unidade ASSIS', -22.6575047, -50.397561, 'Rua Antônio da Silva Cunha Bueno, 425, Jardim Paulista, Assis - SP, 19815-080'],
['Unidade Paulinia', -22.743178, -47.1744984, 'Avenida João Aranha, 946, Alto de Pinheiros, Paulínia - SP, 13145-256'],
['Unidade SBC Centro', -23.7132318, -46.5532384, 'Rua Joaquim Nabuco, 56, Centro, São Bernardo do Campo - SP, 09720-375'],
['Unidade - Chácara', -23.6290144, -46.7025941, 'Rua da paz, 1498, Chácara Santo Antônio, São Paulo - SP, 04713-000'],
['Unidade Buriti', -23.2230818, -46.8760877, 'Rua Dom Pedro I, 462, Jardim Buriti, Várzea Paulista - SP, 13225-790'],
['Unidade BOA VISTA', -14.8793362, -40.832031, 'Avenida Gilenilda Alves, 1345, Boa Vista, Vitória da Conquista - BA, 45027-560'],
['Unidade Valinhos', -22.9623421, -46.9786923, 'Rua Lino Buzatto, 855, Jardim Pinheiros, Valinhos - SP, 13274-440'],
['Unidade nutriton', -5.8005449, -35.203111, 'Rua Joaquim Fagundes, 688, Barro vermelho, Natal - RN, 59022-500'],
        ];

var image = 'https://www.xxxx.xxx/assets/images/mark-01.png';

        function initMap() {

            var myOptions = {
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(-26.1698353, -75.404261),
              zoom: 4,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

            setMarkers(map,locations);

        }

function setMarkers(map,locations){

            var marker, i

            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  

                var loan = locations[i][0]
                var lat = locations[i][1]
                var long = locations[i][2]
                var add =  locations[i][3]

                latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
                    map: map,
                    title: loan,
                    position: latlngset,
                    icon: image
                });

                var circulo = new google.maps.Circle(
                {
                  map: map,
                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
                  radius: 2000, // 1000 metros = 1k.
                  strokeColor: "#818c99",
                  fillColor: "#ffffff",
                  fillOpacity: 0.70
                });

                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())

                var content = "<h5>" + loan + '</h5>' + "<strong>Endereço:</strong> " + add;

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(content);
                        infowindow.open(map,marker);
                    };
                })(marker,content,infowindow));

            }

        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('body').attr('onload', 'initMap();');
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Sua pergunta ficou muito em aberto, portanto, não é possível responde-la por completo. O tratamento de cores/distância dos marcadores será implementada de acordo com a lógica da sua aplicação, de que forma os dados são recuperados e que eventos serão disparados para execução da mesma. A respeito do agrupamento dos marcadores a [documentação do Clustering de marcadores pode te ajudar.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering?hl=pt-br)